# Is it possible to modify a firefox addon written using XUL with an addon written using the Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to write an addon which enhances an existing addon (e.g., adding an options dialog). I do not want to modify the original addon's code directly. The original addon I wish is written using XUL. 
Does this mean I have to write my addon using XUL as well? Or can I use the newer Addon SDK?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not select the best answer if it answered your query?

Comment: @Kashif, right you are.

Comment: You might look at this thread, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506744/how-to-overlay-an-xul-file-from-another-extension-in-a-bootstrapped-add-on-or-o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to extend other add-ons. There are actually quite a few add-ons that either extend or interact with other add-ons, for example Element Hiding Helper extending Adblock Plus and lots of Firebug add-ons.

How to do it depends on the implementation of actual add-on you're trying to extend. Hence, I can only give you some general pointers/notes:

- You can have XUL overlays to add-on XUL windows/overlays, just like you may have some for `browser.xul` or other core code.
- You can, of course, use the DOM APIs as well to manipulate any third party XUL DOM.
- You can [monkey-patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Appendix_C:_Avoid_using_eval_in_Add-ons#Overriding.2FExtending_existing_functions) global functions and objects in Javascript and/or replace/wrap most XPCOM components.
- The Add-on SDK cannot use overlays. Hence you have to use `window/utils` or similar means to get to the XUL windows and can use DOM APIs from there.
- There are certain ways to monkey-patch code in Javascript code modules, if you really have to...
- Monkey-patching of SDK modules and/or content-scripts is extremely hard and extremely fragile from what I remember.
- It is always good to ping the author of an add-on for help, feedback or just for a heads-up. Often authors might be even willing to expose their own extension APIs to make their add-ons easier to extend. E.g. I created such APIs in the past and also had other authors create APIs for me.

Comment: Thanks, I need to extend an existing addon, and I wanted to know if it's better to use the addon SDK over the older XUL format. Since manipulating the menus using the DOM API is probably the less desirable option, I think I'll use the XUL.

Comment: Yep, using the SDK might actually be more complicated in this case.